# Installing ColdFusion 9.0.1 Updates and JVM

Tags: java, jvm, coldfusion-9

I am updating ColdFusion 9 to 9.0.1, I followed all the steps mentioned in https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/cumulative-hotfix-4-coldfusion-901.html. Then followed instructions on https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/change-coldfusion-jvm.html. Copied MSVCR100.dll from C:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre\bin\ folder to CF9\runtime\bin. Changed the config.jvm to Java.home=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_80/jre. Then Restarted the ColdFusion Server and I got the following Error
[enter image description here]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qovy0.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qovy0.png

Help Needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path within your jvm.config file (note that it is not config.jvm as you mentioned) should not include the 'jre' folder. It also seems like you have to double up the slashes to escape them.  It should look like this:

```
java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_80
```

That should get you passed that error.

*All of these versions are unsupported of course. You should upgrade to supported versions. You will keep running into issues.*

Comment: It worked correctly but still my ColdFusion server is displaying the JVM Version 1.6.0_14. This should be another question but I request if answered I updated the CF9 server Still my version is 9,0,0,251028. On running jRun I found out this  Ignoring invalid file in updates directory: chf9010004.jar